# Reliably Closing Realm (Fragments)

Tags: android, android-fragments, realm

I'm working on an application that is utilizing realm, and also fragments. The realm setup requires encryption, and the realm db to be deleted and new keys to be generated when a user signs out.

In order to perform the sign out I launch a new activity at the top of the task that doesn't have any fragments, and launch an IntentService that handled all my sign out cleanup.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to reliably get my fragments to let go of their realm instances to allow the realm to be deleted. Closing the realm in the fragments in onStop/onPause/onDestroy, there are always still one or two fragments that seem to take their sweet time in getting shut down/cleared from Android's fragment cache.

I've switched my view pagers to use FragmentStatePagerAdapers, which reduced the number of fragments open and helped a little bit.

So in my IntentService I've taken to looping over the Realm.delete() until it succeeds - which it eventually seems to do. Sometimes the wait is very short, some times it's minutes. It's highly variable.

The one thought I had was to fire off an event (using EventBus) that the fragments listen for that will cause them to close their realm instances.

But is there a better way to get my fragments to shutdown/close their realm instances in a timely fashion (besides not using fragments at all)?

RealmFragment.java:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;

import io.realm.Realm;

public class RealmFragment extends Fragment {
    private Realm realm = null;
    private final Object realmLock = new Object();

    public Realm getRealm() {
        if (realm == null || realm.isClosed()) {
            synchronized (realmLock) {
                if (realm == null || realm.isClosed()) {
                    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                }
            }
        }
        return realm;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        closeRealm();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        closeRealm();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        closeRealm();
    }

    private void closeRealm() {
        if (realm != null && !realm.isClosed()) {
            synchronized (realmLock) {
                if (realm != null && !realm.isClosed()) {
                    try {
                        realm.close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("REALM","Couldn't close realm.");
                    }
                    realm = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Sign in screen launch:

```
    case R.id.logout: {
       AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
       .setTitle(R.string.confirm_sign_out)
       .setMessage(R.string.sign_out_description)
       .setPositiveButton(
          android.R.string.ok, 
          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // close this activity's realm before launching sign out.
               MyActivity.closeRealm();
               Intent signOutIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, SignOutActivity.class);
               signOutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
               // this starts the logout process. It begins with removing an Android 
               // system account, and a receiver that listens for that to complete. When 
               // the account removal is complete, then we can continue with the rest of
               // the logout process.
               Actions.logoutAccount(getApplicationContext());
               startActivity(signOutIntent);
               // I could call this before calling startActivity()?
               MyActivity.finish();
            }
      })
     .setNegativeButton(
        android.R.string.cancel, 
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              dialog.dismiss();
           }
      })
     .setCancelable(true)
     .create();
     alertDialog.show();
     break;
   }
```

Comment: I personally would recommend opening a single Realm instance in a retained fragment's constructor or `onCreate()` then bind the fragment to your Activity, and close the realm in `onDestroy()`. That way, there'd be only one shared Realm, and it'd be bound to the activity lifecycle with no caching. And you would get the reference to that Realm into your Activity from that retained fragment, and your other fragments would get their Realm reference from the Activity.

Comment: Fragment lifecycle is notoriously difficult. Have you tried looking into http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean) or haps controlling your task stack so you force all activities to be closed when you open your login/logout screen?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - The realm instance is acquired lazily, rather than in the onCreate() - I had too many issues with the instance becoming invalid.  I'll add the code I'm using above.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior - I'm opening the logout screen with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION will post code for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

The Fragment lifecycle was indeed the problem.  I was able to resolve this issue thanks to the hint provided @ChrisitianMelchior in the comments above. The key was to set the following flags on the activity like so:

`signOutIntent.setFlags(
   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |
   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
);`

This caused the previous activity(-ies) and their fragments to get shutdown, which unlocked the realm.

Comment: Ugh, this was working fine and seemed to be good for a couple of hours. I just tried it again, and am still stuck with the same problem. This is not a complete fix.

Comment: One alternative solution could perhaps be to just create a Realm for each user? Then you can delete the older Realms in a more controlled way, e.g when starting the app?

Comment: I created a RealmMonitor singleton class that proxies all my calls to Realm.getInstance() and realm.close(), with RealmMonitor.getInstance(Object o) and RealmMonitor.close(Object o, Realm realm);

This allows me to track opens and closes.  As expected, there's a delay when shutting down fragments, but what was unexpected is there appears to be a delay shutting down activities.
I have a launcher/controller activity, which based on certain conditions delegates to other activities.  I've overridden startActivity() in it:

Comment: Continue: I have a launcher/controller activity, which based on certain conditions delegates to other activities.  It will launch the SignInActivity or MainActivity as appropriate- and I'm seeing it still holding onto a realm instance even though the sign out activity is 3 levels deep, and I'm calling MainActivity and SignOutActivity with flags that _should_ be clearing the task stack. However I'm seeing LauncherActivity still around and holding onto it's realm - sometimes.